# Passing a value from activity to thread after thread is already created

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

In my android program an Activity calls a new surface view class, which then in turn calls a new thread class. I want to be able to pass a value to the thread class from the activity's onPause and onResume methods, so I can pause and resume the thread. The only way I know to pass this data is by creating a new instance, which would just create a different thread. How should I go about this without creating a new thread instance?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new GameSurface(this));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
            //Would like to pass this value
            int state = 1;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
            //Would like to pass this value
            int state = 2;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with 2 classes and a working implementation of the `AtomicInteger`. Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A little background on concurrency**

Passing values in concurrency is the easy part. Look into the `AtomicInteger` data type (More information [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)). Atomicity also means `All or nothing`. This data type isn't necessarily sending data between threads or processors (like you would with `mpi`) but it is merely sharing data on its shared memory.

**But what is an Atomic Action?....**

> An atomic operation is an operation which is performed as a single unit of work without the possibility of interference from other operations.
>
> In Java the language specification guarantees that reading or writing a variable is atomic (unless the variable is of type long or double). Long and double are only atomic if they declared as volatile....
>
> *Credit([Java Concurrency / Multithreading - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#memorymodel_atomic) by Lars Vogel)*

I highly recommend you read this, it covers everything from `atomicity`, `thread pools`, `deadlocks` and `the "volatile" and "synchronized" keyword`.

---

**Start Class** *This will execute a new thread* (It can also be referred to as our `Main Thread`).

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
/**
 * @author Michael Jones
 * @description Main Thread
 */
public class start {
    private AtomicInteger state;
    private Thread p;
    private Thread r;
    /**
     * constructor
     * initialize the declared threads
     */
    public start(){
        //initialize the state
        this.state = new AtomicInteger(0);
        //initialize the threads r and p
        this.r = new Thread(new action("resume", state));
        this.p = new Thread(new action("pause", state));
    } //close constructor

    /**
     * Start the threads
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public void startThreads() throws InterruptedException{
        if(!this.r.isAlive()){
            r.start(); //start r
        }
        if(!this.p.isAlive()){
            Thread.sleep(1000); //wait a little (wait for r to update)...
            p.start(); //start p
        }
    } //close startThreads

    /**
     * This method starts the main thread
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //call the constructor of this class
        start s = new start();
        //try the code
        try {
            s.startThreads();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //start the threads
    } //close main

} //close class start
```

*Because the integer is atomic, you can also retrieve it anywhere but the `main method` in the **Start Class** with `System.out.println("[run start] current state is... "+state.intValue());`.* (If you wish to retrieve it from the `main method`, you will have to setup a Setter/Getter, like I've done so in the **Action Class**)

**Action Class** *This is our thread in action* (It can also be referred to as our `Slave Thread`).

```
import java.lang.Thread.State;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * @author Michael Jones
 * @description Slave Thread
 */
public class action implements Runnable {

    private String event = "";
    private AtomicInteger state;

    /**
     * The constructor (this represents the current instance of a thread).
     * 
     * @param event
     * @param state
     */
    public action(String event, AtomicInteger state) {
        this.event = event; // update this instance of event
        this.state = state; // update this instance of state
    } // constructor

    /**
     * This method will be called after YourThreadName.Start();
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (this.event == "resume") {
            this.OnResume(); // call resume
        } else {
            this.OnPause(); // call pause
        }
    } // close Runnable run() method

    /**
     * The resume function Use the auto lock from synchronized
     */
    public synchronized void OnResume() {
        System.out.println("[OnResume] The state was.." + this.getAtomicState()
                + " // Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        this.setAtomicState(2); // change the state
        System.out.println("[OnResume] The state is.." + this.getAtomicState()
                + " // Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    } // close function

    /**
     * The pause function Use the auto lock from synchronized
     */
    public synchronized void OnPause() {
        System.out.println("[OnPause] The state was.." + this.getAtomicState()
                + " // Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        this.setAtomicState(1); // change the state
        System.out.println("[OnPause] The state is.." + this.getAtomicState()
                + " // Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    } // close function

    /**
     * Get the atomic integer from memory
     * 
     * @return Integer
     */
    private Integer getAtomicState() {
        return state.intValue();
    }// close function

    /**
     * Update or Create a new atomic integer
     * 
     * @param value
     */
    private void setAtomicState(Integer value) {
        if (this.state == null) {
            state = new AtomicInteger(value);
        } else
            state.set(value);
    } // close function

} // close the class
```

**The Console Output**

```
[OnResume] The state was..0 // Thread: 9
[OnResume] The state is..2 // Thread: 9
[OnPause] The state was..2 // Thread: 10
[OnPause] The state is..1 // Thread: 10
```

As you can see, the `AtomicInteger state` is being shared in the memory between our threads `r` and `p`.

---

**Solution and Things to look for...**

The only thing you have to watch when doing concurrency is `Race Conditions`/`Deadlocks`/`Livelocks`. Some `RaceConditions` occur because `Threads` are created in random order (And most programmers think in the mind set of sequential order).

I have the line `Thread.sleep(1000);` so that my `Main Thread` gives the slave thread `r` a little time to update the `state` (before allowing `p` to run), *due to the random order of threads*.

> 1) Keep a reference to the thread and pass the value with a method.
>   *Credit ([SJuan76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598289/sjuan76), 2012)*

In the solution I've posted I make my `Main Thread` (aka `class start`) as my main communicator to keep track of the `Atomic Integer` for my slaves to use (aka `class action`). My main thread is also `updating` the `memory buffer` for the `Atomic Integer` on my slaves **(The update on the memory buffer occurs in the background of the application and is handled by the `AtomicInteger` class)**.

Comment: Thanks. So do I have to use an AtomicInteger constructor or method to in the thread class to get the updated state? Sorry if that's not right. Java is pretty new to me.

Comment: You have to use the AtomicInteger declaration in each class (say I have a class `foo` which creates a thread with the class `boo`) I would need my `AtomicInteger x` declared in both classes in order for it to be shared across memory.

Comment: Also add `synchronized` to your `onPause()` and `onResume()`, for example `protected synchronized void onResume()`. This enables auto locking to the thread or variable `state`. And will avoid a possible `Race Condition`. Regards

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its still not being shared correctly. In the activity class the AtomicInteger stays null the whole time. Do I have to initially pass the AtomicInteger in before it will work?

Comment: Hey zkello, I did some code in eclipse this time using `AtomicInteger` and posted my results above. As you see the state is recorded between threads. Regards

Comment: @Zkello your problem is that you haven't initialized it inside the class that is the `main() Thread` or `init()` (for applets). I have edited my post. Anyone is welcome to use and play around with the code. Regards

Comment: Your answer went above and beyond! Thanks Killrawr!

Answer (score 4):

1) Keep a reference to the thread and pass the value with a method.

2) During the thread creation, pass it an object shared with the Activity. Put the values to pass into the object, have the thread check it regularly until the values are found.

Comment: wouldn't the first solution cause possible race conditions ? if either `onResume` or `onPause` rely on one another?

Answer (score 2):

I use the reference class that i name it `Share Class`. It has the variable with `volatile` type.

> **volatile** is used to indicate that a variable's value will be modified
>   by different *threads*.

```
public class Share {
   public static volatile type M_shared;
}
```

to change this variable, you should lock it and after change the value, release the lock. You can read and write using `Share.M_shared`.